# Ckeditor link text to file

Tags: 8, wysiwyg, files

I'm creating a content type on Drupal 8, which will contain a text that's linked to PDF file.

In Drupal 7, it was just easy with some useful modules. Is it possible to link a text to a PDF file using CKEditor in Drupal 8?

Comment: Mhhh, it's not clear what the problem? You can select the text and make it a link to any source, including your PDF file (which is already available on server).

Comment: @Eugene Is that possible in Drupal 8? when I select text and try to link, I only see url option.

Comment: the selected text will become clickable. What the problem?

Comment: As I mentioned above, I'm trying to add a file to the text. So, eventually, if the user clicks the text, pdf file should pop up in a new tab

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can upload file separately and after that add the link to this file.
Or you can use module [IMCE](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce) to upload files in WYSIWYG and add link on them easily.

Comment: That would be good too. I was only looking for a way to directly upload the file to a text. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I understand. Previously somebody from my team did something like this for D7 and it was custom plugin for ckeditor.

Answer (score 1):

This Drupal 8 module does exactly that, in a tightly integrated way: https://www.drupal.org/project/editor_file